# I am inputting values to my Firestore database but they are not going into the correct fields

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I am scanning a QR code and then updating my attendance collection in Cloud Firestore. It is not putting them in the correct place and I am using a model class of type `Attendance`. Here is my code:

```
 final FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        final DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("Session").document(rawValue);
                        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                    if (document.exists()) {

                                        Date timeToCheck = calendar.getTime();
                                        Session session = document.toObject(Session.class);
                                        Date startTime = session.getStartTime();
                                        Date endTime = session.getEndTime();
                                        if (timeToCheck.after(startTime) && (timeToCheck.before(endTime))) {
                                            Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue, userUID, date, userEmail);
                                            attendanceRef3.add(attendance);
                                            Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this,
                                                    "Your attendance has been recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this,
                                                    "You are outside the time parameters for this session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this,
                                                "Session does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is my model class code for attendance: I am creating an object of type attendance and trying to input this. Currently they are going in the wrong places and I have tried changing them to match how they look exactly in the attendance constructor already:

```
package com.dissertation.studentscanner;

public class Attendance {

private String sessionID;
private String userUID;
private String signInTime;
private String userEmail;

public Attendance(){
    //public no-arg constructor needed
}



public Attendance(String userUID){
    this.userUID = userUID;
}

public Attendance (String sessionID, String userUID){
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    this.userUID = userUID;
}

public Attendance( String sessionID, String date, String userEmail, String userUID){
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    this.signInTime = date;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    this.userUID = userUID;

}

public String getSessionID(){
    return sessionID;
}

public String getUserUID(){
    return userUID;
}

public String getSignInTime(){
    return signInTime;
}

public String getUserEmail(){
    return userEmail;
}
```

It is still coming up this way

[image]

Comment: What specifically in your code is doing something different than what you expected? Please also add your database structure and indicate the place where you want the data to be added.

Comment: Alex currently the correct data is being input but it is going to the wrong fields. i.e my signInTime is going into my userEmail field etc.

Comment: I understand now. I'll write you an answer right now.

Comment: Thank you Alex it is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you comment, this is happening because when you are adding data to the database using an object of your `Attendance` class, you pass to the constructor values in an incorrect order. The constructor is declared as follows:

```
public Attendance( String sessionID, String date, String userEmail, String userUID)
```

So when you create a new object of the `Attendance` class you should pass to the constructor the following values:

```
Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue, date, userEmail, userUID);
```

and not:

```
Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue, userUID, date, userEmail);
```

As it is in your code now. See the right order?

Comment: no alex it still is coming up in the wrong order no matter which way I insert the values?

Comment: It cannot be as long as you pass the values to the constructor in the correct order. But please be aware that you need to add fresh data. Delete the old data and add new one and be sure to pass in the exact order as it is in your model class. Does it work now?

Comment: This answer looks to be good! I would suggest to clear the database and then try adding fresh data.

Comment: does the name of the variables being passed in have to match the exact names of how they are described in the constructor?

Comment: @SeanGallagher No, you should pass the values in the exact order. In your constructor, the first field is the `sessionID` so when you create the object the first argumenbt should be the session id, the second should mandatory be the `date`, the third the `userEmail` and the last one the `userUID`.

Comment: @SeanGallagher As I already told you, please remove the old values direct from the Console and add fresh data, right?